# Meteor publish subscribe is not reactive

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

My client subscription routines are not refreshing when I update a collection:

**server/publish.js**

```
Meteor.publish('decisions', function (decisionCursor) {
    return Decisions.find({ active: true }, { limit: 20, skip: decisionCursor });
});

Meteor.publish('decisionsToModerate', function (decisionCursor) {
    return Decisions.find({ active: false }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: 1, skip: decisionCursor });
});
```

I subscribe my client to both collection publications and when it fetchs all data it creates a session object with some stuff I need.

**client/client.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    SimpleSchema.debug = true;
    Deps.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.subscribe("decisions", Number(Session.get('decisionCursor')), function () {
            var decisionsVoted = {};
            Decisions.find({
                active: true
            }).forEach(function (decision) {
                var userVoted = Meteor.users.findOne({
                    "_id": Meteor.userId(),
                    "profile.votes.decision": decision._id
                }) != null ? Meteor.users.findOne({
                    "_id": Meteor.userId(),
                    "profile.votes.decision": decision._id
                }) : false;

                var ipVoted = Votes.findOne({
                    "ip": headers.get('x-forwarded-for'),
                    "votes.decision": decision._id
                }) != null ? true : false;
                if (ipVoted || userVoted)
                    decisionsVoted[decision._id] = {
                        voted: true,
                        blue: decision.blueTotal,
                        red: decision.redTotal,
                        bluePer: Math.round(decision.blueTotal * 100) / (decision.blueTotal + decision.redTotal),
                        redPer: Math.round(decision.redTotal * 100) / (decision.blueTotal + decision.redTotal)
                    };

            });
            Session.set('decisionsVoted', decisionsVoted);
        });
        Meteor.subscribe("decisionsToModerate", Number(Session.get('decisionCursor')));
    });
});
```

**client/lib/environment.js**

```
activeDecisions = function() {
    var decisions = Decisions.find({active: true});
    console.log(decisions.fetch().length);
    return decisions;
};
moderateDecisions = function() {
    return Decisions.find({active: false});
};
```

**client/views/home/home.js**

```
'click': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var decisionId = Session.get("selected_decision");
    var hasVoted = Session.get('decisionsVoted')[decisionId] ? Session.get('decisionsVoted')[decisionId].voted : false;

    Meteor.call("vote", decisionId, 'blue', hasVoted, function (error, result) {
        if (!error && result === true) {
            console.log(Session.get('decisionsVoted')[decisionId]); // UNDEFINED
        }
    });
},
```

When updating is successful, client subscriptioun should update creating a new object in my session object, right? Because collection is changed so publish in server is refreshed... But it does not refresh and what I commented `// UNDEFINED` instead of returning my new object is returning `UNDEFINED`

I don't know if that's the behaviour of Meteor or I'm missing something... I've tried to update parameter passed to publish method `decisionCursor` in order to force update but nothing hapens `Session.set('decisionCursor', Session.get('decisionCursor'));`

**EDIT:** it seems that if I use `Session.set('decisionCursor', Session.get('decisionCursor') + 1);` (note that +1) it is refreshed but not inside result function, if I click again it detects that new object is added... But I need it to be refreshed inside result function (inside my `home.js` click event)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This (excellent) article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/) might help. To paraphrase:

> ...on the server, Meteor’s reactivity is limited to cursors returned by Meteor.publish() functions. The direct consequence of this is that unlike on the client, code will not magically re-run whenever data changes.

Answer (score 2):

The callback to `Meteor.subscribe` is called when the server marks the subscription as ready, and is not a reactive context, so it won't re-run when its dependencies change. (Reactive contexts aren't inherited like closure variables, the fact the callback is physically inside of the autorun is irrelevant.) You probably want a second `autorun`:

```
// original autorun
Deps.autorun(function() {
  var decSubscription = Meteor.subscribe("decisions", Number(Session.get('decisionCursor')));
  Meteor.subscribe("decisionsToModerate", Number(Session.get('decisionCursor')));

  // Store the subscription handle in a session variable so that
  // the new autorun re-runs if we resubscribe
  Session.set("decSubscription", decSubscription);
});

// new autorun
Deps.autorun(function() {
  // don't do anything if the subscription isn't ready yet
  var decCursor = Session.get("decSubscription");
  if (!decCursor.ready()) {
    Session.set("decisionsVoted", {});
    return;
  }
  var decisionsVoted = {};
  Decisions.find({active: true}).forEach(/* ... */);
  Session.set("decisionsVoted", decisionsVoted);
});
```

Note that we skip computing `decisionsVoted` if the subscription isn't ready, otherwise when the server is sending the initial result set, we will recompute it after each individual document is sent.