# Weird behavior with Meteor subscription (client collection of wrong size)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have a *Meteor pet project* where, for learning purposes, I implemented traditional pagination. This means, I display only a subset of all the records the Mongo collection holds, and I have "next" and "prev" buttons, and a dropdown menu to select the amount of results to show per page.

Sometimes I have this weird glitch when I click "next" of "prev", like if the list of results was a little bit longer. That can be seen for a fraction of a second, then results are displayed fine.

So I checked the size of my collections and it seems that the mini-mongo collection sometimes has a bigger size than it should. That explains the effect, but I don't know why I am producing that behavior in my code.

On server side, I make my collections available with:

```
/** Publish all scenarios from the current user
@cursorStart, skip parameter
@recordLimit, limit parameter
@sortPreferences, object to sort the published cursor
*/
Meteor.publish('myScenarios', function(cursorStart, recordLimit, sortPreferences){
    var objSort = {};//object to sort the cursor
    console.log("Record limit# "+recordLimit);
    if(sortPreferences){
      objSort[sortPreferences.param] = sortPreferences.order;
    }else{
      objSort['createdAt'] = 1;
    }
    Mongo.Collection._publishCursor( 
      Scenarios.find({owner: this.userId }, {limit :recordLimit, skip : cursorStart, sort : objSort}), 
      this, 'myScenarios'); 
    this.ready();
});
```

This way, if I want to show 10 results per page I publish only 10 records of my collection, instead of sending the whole collection to the client.

On the corresponding template's event, upon the user clicking the "next" or "prev" buttons I'll update *session* variables that hold which results I want to show. For example

```
"click .next" : function(){
  var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
  scenarioCount = scenarioTotalCount(routeName);//get the total size of this collection
  if(Number(Session.get('scenarioCursorStart')) + Number(Session.get('scenarioResultsPerPage')) < scenarioCount)
   Session.set('scenarioCursorStart', Number(Session.get('scenarioCursorStart'))+Number(Session.get('scenarioResultsPerPage')));
}
```

*scenarioCursorStart* is the *skip* parameter, used to know if I'm showing first 10 results, the second 10 (meaning, 10 to 19), etc. *scenarioResultsPerPage* would be updated upon changes on the dropdown, when the user says that he or she wants to display a different number of results per page. The is also another object involved, which I use to indicate by which field I want to sort these results. Anyway, only the skip parameter *scenarioCursorStart* is modified upon clicking the "next" or "prev" buttons.

On client side I'm subscribed to this collection like

```
MyScenarios = new Mongo.Collection('myScenarios');
...
Deps.autorun(function(){
...
Meteor.subscribe('myScenarios', Number(Session.get('scenarioCursorStart')), Number(Session.get('scenarioResultsPerPage')), Session.get('scenarioCursorOrder'));  //scenarios of the current user

}
```

If I *console.log* the size of my mini-mongo collection there (
    console.log("list size: "+ MyScenarios.find().count())
) I get that upon clicking "next" (which updates the *skip* parameter *scenarioCursorStart* but none of the others) the size is for example 10, then 20 (or 12) and then 10 again. If I *console.log* on server size the *skip* and *limit* parameters they always have the correct values, so I'm not publishing a cursor of different size or starting at a different record form what I want.

My understanding is that I have a problem on my subscription since the length of the collections varies (and is not always double, which would be easier to "diagnose". If I'm requesting 10 results per page sometimes I get a length of 20, sometimes 12 or 13. The "glitch" is not consistent) but the parameters on server side seem to be fine.

I'm completely stuck at what to look for next or where to look. I would appreciate any help trying to find the cause of this issue. Maybe I have a blatant issue with Meteor Pub-sub mechanism, but can't figure out what that is not working as expected.

Comment: BTW, I could _patch_ this by adding a _limit_ when rendering (after all, I need to re-sort the collection on client) but I would much rather understand what is going on with that weird pub-sub behavior and where did I go wrong. Quick fix --> this.render('scenarioListTable', 
      {data : { scenarios : MyScenarios.find({}, {**limit: Number(Session.get('scenarioResultsPerPage'))**, sort: objSort}) }} );

Answer (score 0):

You could try stopping the previous subscription before subscribing for the new one.

Assuming the code is in your onRendered/onCreated function, you could try:

```
var instance = this;

Deps.autorun(function() {
    if( this.subscription != null ) {
        this.subscription.stop();
    }
    this.subscription = Meteor.subscribe('myScenarios',
        Number(Session.get('scenarioCursorStart')),
        Number(Session.get('scenarioResultsPerPage')),
        Session.get('scenarioCursorOrder')
    );
}
```

Also, I think `Deps` was changed to `Tracker` a few releases ago, you might want to start using `Tracker` sometime.

Comment: I thought that _Meteor.subscribe_ is not a reactive context, but I have a "infinite loop" effect. Without doing anything on my app I can see that piece of code being executed several times. I had my _console.log_ there I can can see it being continuously printed on the console, and the data being rendered continuously changing (with a _flashing_ effect). The length of my mini-mongo collections goes from 0 (to 1 to 5 to 0 to 7...) to 10, and on and on. I can use a [second autorun](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23776901/3961519) but although that gets rid of the effect it doesn't fix my problem.